# How to remove the border around a plot made with sm.density.compare()?

Tags: r

I've got some data that I'd like to plot using `sm.density.compare()` from package `sm`. It all looks fine. But how do I remove the border/frame around the plot area? I've tried:

```
sm.density.compare(..., frame = FALSE)
```

As well as

```
sm.density.compare(..., bty = "n")
```

But that all doesn't work. I can't find the solution immediately in the documentation of `sm.density.compare()`.

Comment: you could just do `par(bty='n')` to change it globally (then change it back)

Comment: Thank you! That worked marvellously!